# SQL Statement to get Daily Totals across two days instead of Midnight

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-ce

I recently wrote a query to get daily totals over a month. The Query works just fine but it does midnight to midnight. I need to find the totals from 7:15 am until 7:15 am the next day. We run three shifts starting at 7:15.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,CAST(t_stamp AS DATE)), COUNT(bottles) AS 'Good Bottles'
FROM bottles
WHERE t_stamp
    BETWEEN starrt
    AND end
GROUP BY CAST(t_stamp AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(t_stamp AS DATE) ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subtract an offset.  A simple way is:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(minute, -(7 * 60 + 15), t_stamp) AS DATE),
       COUNT(bottles) AS GoodBottles
FROM bottles
WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN starrt AND end
GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD(minute, -(7 * 60 + 15), t_stamp) AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(DATEADD(minute, -(7 * 60 + 15), t_stamp) AS DATE) ASC;
```

Note that `end` is a very bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.

Comment: That Works Great! How to I return a 0 if there is no Value between 7:15 am previous day and 7:15 am current day? This query is used to display totals over a month.

Comment: @Roland . . . That is a different question.  A calendar table is handy for that.  If you cant figure it out, ask a *new* question.